# Laravel 5.5 - display config options as default input value

Tags: forms, laravel, input

I want to add 'Config edit' page where i could edit current config options.
I've implemented function to update the config after form submitting, but now i want to display current options in form on load.
Ex. i open the page and see 'My website' value in 'Website title' field.
I searched on the internet but didn't found something similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the second parameter of {{old('')}}:

`<input name="mail_server" value="{{ old('mail_server', config('mail.host')) }}" />`